# Can I go to jannah without having wife?

Tags: wife

as-salam walai-kum dear brothers and sisters,

I'm a young man 23 years old from Bangladesh.
I'm here to ask u "if i don't marry, is there a problem?"
Can I go to the jannah without having a wife?
I don't have girlfriends, affairs with female friends .
I'm physically and mentally normal.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. To your question what makes you think you can't go to jannah unless you have a wife? The rest of your question has already been asked and answered on the site.